# Open Downloads folder on clicking push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

In my android app, when a user click on download button, a push notification display with a progress bar, on download complete, if a user click on that notification then user should be taken to the Downloads folder of the users mobile. I implemented the following code to achieve this --

```
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(VideoPlayActivity.this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("File Download")
                    .setContentText("Download in progress")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.doupnowlogo)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading file...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

But on clicking the notification, nothing happens, kindly guide.

Comment: Why are you calling that a push notification?

Comment: You could try that intent from the button onClick handler directly. Did you ever see such work? It is a nonsense intent to begin with.

Comment: Which button click, its a notification man. @greenapps

Comment: `when a user click on download button`. So try to open intent directly. Without using a notification. Without downloading. Test your intent only.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your base intent that you are using.
In order to open the downloads folder you should use this intent instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS)
```